# Weights on dialog window layout

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, bluetooth

I have an app where I find bluetooth devices. When I start the search, appears a dialog window, wich shows in the upper side, paired devices, and below of it, appears new found devices.

This window is the same of the bluetooth chat example, I got it from there.

What happens is that if you have several paired devices, the space for new devices gets very small. [image: 1]

This is the code for this dialog window:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView android:id="@+id/title_paired_devices"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/title_paired_devices"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="#666"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

<ListView android:id="@+id/paired_devices"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/title_new_devices"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/title_other_devices"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="#666"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>

<ListView android:id="@+id/new_devices"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:layout_weight="2"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/button_scan"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_scan"/>
```

Comment: divide your screen in two sections according to the device height,and set the height of both the listview at run time

Comment: Or you can use expandable `ListView`.

Comment: @Meenal Sharma how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I used this code ,and i divided my screen in the ration of 20-80

```
try {

             private int imageHeight1, imageHeight2;
            Display mDisplay = getActivity().getWindowManager()
                    .getDefaultDisplay();
            if (Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) < 13) {

                int height = mDisplay.getHeight();
                imageHeight1 = (int) (height * 0.2);
                imageHeight2 = height - imageHeight1;

            } else {

                Point size = new Point();
                mDisplay.getSize(size);

                imageHeight1 = (int) (size.y * 0.2);
                imageHeight2 = size.y - imageHeight1;
            }

            try {
                listview1.getLayoutParams().height = imageHeight1;
                listview2.getLayoutParams().height = imageHeight2;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Would be some way to do it directly on the layout, without using code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".9"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_paired_devices"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#666"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="title_paired_devices"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
             />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/paired_devices"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:stackFromBottom="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_new_devices"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#666"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="title_other_devices"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textIsSelectable="true" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/new_devices"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:stackFromBottom="true" />
    </LinearLayout> </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_scan"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button_scan" /> </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Doesn't do the work right. Only shows half-button. The new devices starts loading from the button. Isn't the best approach for the best performance

Comment: i think you need a transparent image on the background of layout.